# How to get the percentage of color from image_properties in google vision api?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I am trying to use Google Vision API for color detection. For this i am using python library. When i fetch image_properties i get a result something like below

```
colors {
  color {
    red: 52.0
    green: 94.0
    blue: 96.0
  }
  score: 0.11754503101110458
  pixel_fraction: 0.04190981388092041
}
```

But how to calculate the percentage which in this case comes out to be **"18%"**

[Actual Output of the Google Vision Api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsHh3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've gotten this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsHh3.png) using [Vision demo](https://cloud.google.com/vision/#vision-api-demo). This percentage (**18%**) is calculated by taking the [score](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse?hl=ES#colorinfo) for each color record and divide it by the sum of all the scores:

> % "percent" = score / (score1 + score2 + score3 + ... + scoreN)

Comment: Thanks man, this formulae seems to get the right numbers, just one follow up question, what is the importance of pixel_fraction?

Comment: pixel_Fraction shows fraction of pixels the color occupies in the image. For some, it is useful for in-depth image analysis.

Comment: how is it different from percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Convert this output to ProtoBuff and then to json, it will be simple  extraction.

```html
def json_to_hash_dump(vision_response):
    """
    a function defined to take a convert the 
    response from vision api to json object  transformation via protoBuff 

    Args: 
            vision_response 
    Returns: 
            json_object
    """
    from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
    json_obj = MessageToJson((vision_response._pb))
    # to dict items 
    r = json.loads(json_obj)
    return r
```